# SQL- how to join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all from a table called Customer where CustomerID = 'AC001' and I also want to join in another table Pets where the CustomerID(fk) is the same as the CustomerID in Customer table is that possible?

Customer table

```
CustomerID,TypeOfCustomer, FName,Adress,City,State,Zipcode,PhoneNr,FaxNr
```

Pets table

```
PetID,FName, Animal,Breed,Gender,DoB,CustomerID(fk)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic SQL question, here you go: to join the two tables together, do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
JOIN Pets ON Pets.CustomerId=Customer.CustomerID
```

To filter for CustomerID = 'AC001', add a WHERE clause.

Note also that the result won't contain customers without any pets. If you want to include those as well, do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Generally, I'd recommend reading a good beginner-level book on SQL and relational databases to make sure you grasp the underlying concepts here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select //fields you want// from Customer C, Pets P 
    WHERE C.CustomerID=P.CustomerID
```